# NGINX as https-to-http proxy

Tags: proxy, ssl, nginx, https

I have nginx set up on a machine with private IP 192.168.17.70. It forwards https requests from a public IP using a self-signed certificate (this part is working) to a web appliance on 192.168.17.29. The app on this appliance does not support ssl. It does require a username and password to login.

When I hit the proxy server, it seems to forward the https request to the appliance and I get the login dialog from the web application on the appliance. It does not accept the credentials and instead prompts me again. Logging in directly to the machine running nginx on its private ip address gives me the login prompt and accepts the credentials, then displays the content from the appliance correctly.

I suspect that the problem is in translation between http and https mode but I seem to be stuck. Here is what I have after trying multiple solutions from my searching:

```
upstream backend {
    server 192.168.17.29:80;
}

server {

    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx; # my real IP address is here
    include snippets/self-signed.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    location / {

        proxy_pass http://backend;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_set_header    X-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_redirect http:// $scheme://;
    }

}

server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.17.29;
    }


}
```

I'm a newbie at this so any help would be appreciated. What I have posted is what is working in the manner I described.

Earlier I had a configuration where it would accept my username and password but wouldn't render the content from the non-ssl web appliance to the client machine.

Thanks
Steve

Comment: It might be worthwhile to include the non-rendering but successful login configuration as well.

Comment: You have to add authorization header https://serverfault.com/questions/511206/nginx-forward-http-auth-user